# How to tell if an object has been touch by the player in gml code

Tags: 2d, game-maker, gml

Hey am going to give an example of what am trying to do imagine that i have 5 circle sprites and in my gml code i want to do something like this if cirlce_1 was touch then you can touch circle_2 and if circle_2 was touch then you can touch cirlce_3. Please who can help me with this, willing to give a reward via paypal.

Answer (score 2):

Touch events in Game Maker are treated as mouse events. If you want the circles to only allow the player to touch them in order, you can assign each one to have a number and make them all the same object. Take a look at this:

**Script to create circles**

```
counter = 0;
lastball = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){//Make that third part "i += 1" if using a version before Studio
  c = instance_create(floor(random(room_width)), floor(random(room_height)), objCircle);
  lastball++;
  c.myNum = lastball;
  c.radius = 16;//Or whatever radius you want
};
```

The for statement here automatically generates circles around the room, but if you want manual control, try this:

**newCircle()**

```
c = instance_create(argument0, argument1, objCircle);
c.myNum = lastball;
c.radius = 16;
lastball++;
```

This will create a new circle wherever you want and will automatically increment `lastball` as well every time it's called. For instance, you could say `newCircle(16, 27);`.

**In the step code for objCircle**

```
if(mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left) && point_distance(x, y, mouse_x, mouse_y) < radius && counter == myNum){
  counter++;//Or counter += 1 in versions before Studio
  //Insert whatever circles do when clicked here
};
```

The circles can be made to do anything when clicked. Since they're all the same object, perhaps you could use a switch statement so each one does something different depending on its number.

Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.